# TextView alpha animation doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, alpha, translate-animation

I've got a [BubbleTextView](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/packages/apps/Launcher3/src/com/android/launcher3/BubbleTextView.java) which is basically a TextView with some additions used in Launcher3 to display icons on the homescreen. I'm trying to animate this view via this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:startOffset="350"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="200" />

</set>
```

But whenever I start the animation it'll only translate the image and the alpha part won't work, so there is no fade out animation. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that BubbleTextView overrides `onSetAlpha`

```
@Override
protected boolean onSetAlpha(int alpha) {
    if (mPrevAlpha != alpha) {
        mPrevAlpha = alpha;
        super.onSetAlpha(alpha);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Seems to be some relict of older revisions.
Since the implementation is not needed anymore it's safe to either delete the method or return `false` instead.